# Is there a way to sync Google reminders with the Mac ones

Tags: data-synchronization, calendar, reminders, google-calendar

The macOS Calendar/iCal already syncs nicely with the Google variety. Since 2016 and shortly after the iPhone, the Google web calendar was taught how to do [Reminders](https://www.theverge.com/2016/4/5/11371000/google-calendar-web-adds-reminders). Mac OS has its own flavor of Reminders. It would be most productive to be able to use both together. Is that possible?

[image] ..synced to.. [image] ?

Comment: I don't think so since those reminders aren't registered as "Tasks", which is what's synced when you sign in to your google account on your iOS device. https://support.google.com/mail/answer/106237?hl=en

Comment: Yeah, Tasks :-/. They live in Gmail but I find the connection to the calendar much more useful. Both now also overlap mightily. Not much point in using both.

Answer (score 1):

There is a cool implementation of Google Calendars for Mac. See this project: https://github.com/sfirrin/Clean-Google-Calendar

Comment: Does this Google Calendar front-end enable syncing of Reminders?

Comment: I don't think so.